# Topological Invariant of Compact, Connected Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, connectedness

This is a fairly basic-seeming question, but I'm just not seeing the right argument.

We say that a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an $\epsilon$-map if the diameter of $f^{-1}(y)$ is less than $\epsilon$ in $X$ for every $y \in Y$.  If for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $\epsilon$-map from $X$ onto $Y$, we say that $X$ is $Y$-like.

Suppose we are in the setting of compact, connected, metric spaces.  My question is this: Is being $Y$-like a topological invariant, or just an isometry class invariant?  It wouldn't surprise me if it's a (nearly) one-liner, but I'm just frozen in place on this!

I think the result will be the same in the $\sigma$-compact/connected/metric case, so if there's a counterexample it might be easier to construct a $\sigma$-compact one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\diam{\operatorname{diam}}
\def\id{\operatorname{id}}$
Let $d_1, d_2$ be two equivalent metrics on $X$. If $\id\colon (X, d_1) \to (X, d_2)$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. for every $ε > 0$ there is $δ > 0$ such that $d_1(x, y) ≤ δ \implies d_2(x, y) ≤ ε$, then $\diam_{d_1}(A) ≤ δ \implies \diam_{d_2}(A) ≤ ε$. Hence, if $X$ is $Y$-like with respect to $d_1$, then it is $Y$-like with respect to $d_2$. But on a compact space, every continuous map is uniformly continuous.

Also, sometimes the condition of being $Y$-like can be equivalently defined as being an inverse limit of an inverse system of continuous onto the space $Y$. One implication works allways, the other works at least when $Y$ is a polyhedron. See 2.13 in Continuum theory by Nadler.